# With the following code: FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager

Tags: java, android, class, methods, interface

With the following code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

How does this actually work. I am new to Java somewhat and programming.

`FragmentManager` is an abstract class. `getFragmentManager()` is a method of `Activity`. My class extends `Activity`.

How can I use this `Activity` method here is what I am trying to ask?

I have tried other examples of using methods from activity but it does not work. Can anyone tell me why this particular method works and not others?

When i hit ctrl space in Android Studio, I get several other options which I suppose are different class names on the right side of the options listed. `getFragmentManager` shows up for `FragmentManager` but I can not find it in the documentation.  Another option is `getActionBar()` with `ActionBar` on the right but that does not work either. The syntax error message says it does not match with `FragmentManager`.

Thx

Comment: if your class extends `ActionBarActivity`, then you need to use `getSupportActionBar()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`, and `android.support.v4.Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are in the original documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

You might want to learn the basics of Java before starting with Android programming. It will make your life a lot easier.

You cold try this introduction:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: If fragmentManager is not a subclass of Activity class. while instanciating an instance of fragmentManager,  how is it that I can call a method from the Activity class?